# HTML form with jQuery Validation plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have an HTML form.  It's working properly and I want to apply validations on the form. I cannot get jQuery Validate working on this form.

HTML form :

```
<form method="POST" action="/hourtable/" class="form-horizontal" id= "hour_form"  name="hourform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" id="id_dateDue" class="input-xlarge" name="date" readonly="true" />
<input type="text"  class="input-xlarge" name="appid" value="{{gethours}}" />
<input type="text"  class="input-xlarge" name="hours" value="" />
<button class="btn btn-gebo" type="submit" name="asubmit">Submit</button>
```

jQuery:

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function(){

                //* validation
                $('#hour_form').validate({
                    onkeyup: false,
                    errorClass: 'error',
                    validClass: 'valid',
                    rules: {
                        date: { required: true, minlength: 3 },
                        appid: { required: true, minlength: 3 },
                        hours: { required: true, minlength: 3 },
                        refund: { required: true, minlength: 3 }
                    },
                    highlight: function(element) {
                        $(element).closest('div').addClass("f_error");
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            boxHeight()
                        }, 200)
                    },
                    unhighlight: function(element) {
                        $(element).closest('div').removeClass("f_error");
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            boxHeight()
                        }, 200)
                    },
                    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                        $(element).closest('div').append(error);
                    }
                });


            });
        </script>
```

Comment: any error ?? check your console..

Comment: have you added `jQuery` and `jQuery.validate` javascript files into page..?

Comment: What validation plugin have you used? You need to include the particular jquery file first and jquery validate file then. Check with console..

Comment: I don't see an input for the refund field in your code (just an observation). Also, it looks like the JS expects there to be a div in the DOM above the input fields.

Comment: with your code, I have added validate.js in http://jsfiddle.net/VHtww/ In console, I got this error.."boxHeight is not defined".. check and see..

Comment: For any javascript or jquery to work, you need to add jquery in your head section, may be you are missing that section. Check the entire code like any missing brackets or closing tags ect.Any missing in javascript part will not allow the javascript to work.

Answer (score 0):

You have the following general issues.  Some of these are causing problems.

1)  In your OP, you are missing the closing `</form>` tag.

2)  Your `name="date"` field is `required` but it also contains `readonly="true"`.  These two things will never reconcile.  If the user is not allowed to enter data into this field, it will never pass the `required` rule.   Conversely, if you don't want the user to enter data here, then you don't need rules for this field.

3)  You've declared a rule for a field named `refund` but there is no such field shown in your HTML markup.

4)  You've defined `errorClass: 'error'` and `validClass: 'valid'`.  These are the built-in default values so declaring them is completely unnecessary.

5)  In your `highlight`, `unhighlight` and `errorPlacement` callback functions, you are using `.closest('div')` but there are no `div` elements anyplace in your HTML markup.  Within `errorPlacement`, this is causing your validation messages to be suppressed.

6)  In your `highlight/unhighlight` callback functions, you are referencing something called `boxHeight()`, however, there is no such thing anywhere else in your OP.  You have not explained what you're trying to accomplish within these callback functions.

7)  You have `value="{{gethours}}"` in your `appid` field with no explanation about where this comes from.

The following code is working when the above issues are addressed.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    //* validation
    $('#hour_form').validate({
        onkeyup: false,
        rules: {
            date: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 3
            },
            appid: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 3
            },
            hours: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 3
            }
        }
    });

});
```

**HTML**:

```
<form method="POST" action="/hourtable/" class="form-horizontal" id="hour_form" name="hourform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" id="id_dateDue" class="input-xlarge" name="date" /><br/>
    <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" name="appid" /><br/>
    <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" name="hours" /><br/>
    <button class="btn btn-gebo" type="submit" name="asubmit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**DEMO**:  http://jsfiddle.net/GAb8Z/